# Command Prompt "java -version" command result is different from C# "java -version" command result

Tags: java, c#, cmd

Here I am putting a table which shows result of three types of testing for getting JVM version.

1. C# code

   ```
   ProcessStartInfo objProcStartInfo = null;
   Process objProc = null;
   char[] arrcSpilitter = { '\n' };

   objProcStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java", "-version");
   objProcStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   objProcStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
   objProcStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   objProcStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

   objProc = new Process();
   objProc.StartInfo = objProcStartInfo;
   objProc.Start();
   string sJavaInfo = objProc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
   List<string> lstJavaInfo = new List<string>();

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sJavaInfo) == false)
   {
       lstJavaInfo = sJavaInfo.Split(arrcSpilitter).ToList<string>();
   }

   string sJavaBitVersion = "-";
   if (lstJavaInfo.Count >= 2)
   {
       sJavaBitVersion = lstJavaInfo[2];
   }

   sJavaBitVersion = sJavaBitVersion.Trim();
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sJavaBitVersion) == false)
   {
       if (sJavaBitVersion.ToLower().Contains("64-bit") == true)
       {
           sJavaBitVersion = "64";
       }
       else
       {
           sJavaBitVersion = "32";
       }
   }
   Console.WriteLine("Java bit version : " + sJavaBitVersion);
   ```

   in the above code the line
   `sJavaBitVersion = lstJavaInfo[2];`
   gives result as

   ```
   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode, sharing)
   ```

   or

   ```
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
   ```
2. Java Code

   ```
   String s = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");  
   System.out.println("Java bit Version : " + s);
   ```
3. Command Prompt
   On command prompt I executed java -version

[image: Table shows the three results :]

My doubt is in test cases, 5, 8, 9 and 12 why C# result is different from command prompt result, both are having similar command to execute, which is : java -version